# Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I use React, ES6 and get following error message.  I tried different stuff from [here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style) but its not working for me. If I remove "return" I get this error:

> error  Do not use 'new' for side effects  no-new

If I code like this

```
const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => {
  const promise = new Promise(resolve, reject)
  promise()...
```

I cannot access resolve and reject of constructor.

---

### Short

How to get this code working?

```
const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    validation.availableUserEmail(values.email, dispatch)
    .catch(err => reject(err));
  });
};
```

> error  Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body arrow-body-style

Comment: Your first snippet has two issues. 1. `new new` doesn't really make sense. 2. `Promise` takes a single callback that gets passed `resolve` and `reject`. Your second snippet doesn't need `new Promise` at all. The linting error just says remove the `{}`from around the body of your arrow function though.

Comment: It should also be possible to remove *return* from the second snippet since the body is a single statement and returns the result of its evaluation.

Comment: the whole last block as it is never resolves the "new Promise", but since `validation.availableUserEmail` clearly returns a promise, that function can be simplified to `const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => validation.availableUserEmail(values.email, dispatch);`

Comment: @loganfsmyth sorry, I made a mistake by copying the code. But u are right with your second advice.

Comment: @JaromandaX is right. How can I give u credits to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions can be shortened if **you only have one expression, and you wish to return that expression**, so for example, if you wanted a function to return the number you passed in + 1, this is a shortened version: `x => x + 1`.

`new Promise(............)` is a single expression, and you want to return it, so you can (And should, which is why ESLint is complaining) shorten it like so:

```
(values, dispatch) =>
  new Promise(...........)
```

**Moreover**, since `validation.availableUserEmail()` returns a Promise itself, you can drop the Promise constructor altogether (wrapping a Promise with a Promise constructor is an antipattern), so you can simply do:

```
(values, dispatch) =>
  validation.availableUserEmail(.......)
    .catch(.........)
```

Comment: Thanks. Its even working without the .catch() like JaromandaX wrote a comment ealier.

Comment: Maybe the first sentence must be changed to "...you only have one expression, and you wish to return that expression,..."?

Comment: @Rodrirokr Yes, that seems to be a typo! Next time, feel free to use the "suggest edit" feature (You also get 2 point for approved suggested edits ;) )